# Проверка начертания ячейки Excel Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Как с помощью Apache POI проверить начертание ячейки, а именно применен ли полужирный стиль?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(columnNum);
            XSSFCellStyle cs = (XSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle();
            XSSFFont font = cs.getFont();
            font.getBold();
```